# How to save the status of the shopping cart after the page is reloaded?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuetify.js

How to save the status of the shopping cart after the page is reloaded(also need to leave the status of the "purchased" button)? I don't have a server and I use js + vue 2 + vuetify.Items are added to the cart using the article from the json file

Perhaps there are plugins to make this task easier?

Comment: use `localstorage`

Answer (score 0):

You have to save the state of your application using vuex and localStorage API, As changes are made to your shopping cart, you use your app state and that persists your data to the localStorage. On reload, vuex will pick the data from the localStorage using the data that was last stored there.
Here is how that would work in your vuex store:

```
import { saveState } from './utils'
const appState = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('store')) || defaultData
export default new Vuex.Store({
plugins: [saveState],
state: {
    board
},
....
```

The plugin is a function that listens to mutations in your app and saves the data to localStorage

```
export function saveState (store) {
store.subscribe((mutation, state) => {
    localStorage.setItem('board', JSON.stringify(state.board))
})
```

}